# How to trigger headlight washers on 14 ' Audi S4 (B8.5)

Tags: audi, s4

This is driving me crazy but I do not understand what triggers the headlight washers? Looks like sometimes when I turn on windshield washer, I see mist above my hood and I imagine that it is coming from the headlight washers being engaged. But still cannot seem to figure out how exactly do I trigger them exclusively?

Answer (score 5):

It seems the way to trigger the headlight washers is to **just hold the main washers longer**. That would mean to me they cannot be triggered exclusively. If you don't actually *like* the little things, there is a [way to code them out](http://www.audizine.com/forum/showthread.php/573033-Headlight-washers?s=7a3c09a5eb0006aaab4982418b07910d&p=9320708&viewfull=1#post9320708) from the hidden menu if you have access to VAG COM. Change the following:

---

> - Set Headlight washer - Duration
> - [09 – Cent. Elect.]
> - [Security Access - 16] [Adaptation - 10] -> Channel 6
> - change to e.g. 500
>
>   ---
> - Set Headlight washer - Cycles
> - [09 – Cent. Elect.]
> - [Security Access - 16] [Adaptation - 10] -> Channel 26
> - change to e.g. 10
>
>   ---

Comment: This seems to be pretty standard across VW models which have headlight washers; no dedicated headlight washer switch/lever